# Re-apply transformation to another layer (GIMP)

Tags: gimp

I am looking for a way to somehow apply a transformation (stretching, rotation) of an image in one layer to a similar image in another layer.

Comment: Can you move one layer on top of another, select both of them and then transform both layers simultaneously?

Comment: Depending on your OS you may be able to use one of the Gimp batch-processing plug-ins.

Comment: @IvanKuckir I don't know how to select multiple layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "link" both layers (link icon next to the eye icon in the layer list):

[image]

then a geometric transform applied to any of the linked layers is applied to the other linked layers (this happens when you confirm the transform, the WYSIWYG adjustments is done only with the active layer).

Linking works for layers in the same image. You can also link paths and channels (between them, or with layers...).

Comment: This seems to work for "moving" but not "perspective" transformation.  Is that what you'd expect?   With perspective, I get a floating layer of the transformed layer that I am working on, but nothing happens to the linked one

Comment: This is because you have a selection. If you apply the transform to the whole layer, do it without selection.